# How do I save a np with mostly imaginary numbers (complex128) into a .wav file?

Tags: python

I'm trying to save a .wav file as a complex128 but I can't seem to use any library and/or it loses all it's data when forcing a conversion type since I just applied a binary mask onto it

Comment: Imaginary air pressures being unavailable in the `.wav` format, you’d need to define what it **means** to “save […] imaginary numbers” into one.